# How to make a 4X4 div panel inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this simple memory game exercise which calls for using a 4x4 panel of cards, I tried adding a middle div section with the class "panel" that limits the area 460 x 460 which is enough for 4 card divs to fit but it seems not to be working. I have added the 16 card divs for you to see the problem. Ideally, I plan to add those using jQuery.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.columnR {
  flex: 22%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #FF7600;
}

.columnL {
  flex: 77%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #FF5810;
}

.panel div {
  display: flex;
  width: 460;
  height: 460;
}

.card {
  flex: 20%;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #EE872A;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  background: #B1B1B1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card:hover {
  border: 5px solid #EE872A;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="columnL">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnR">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: missing the unit, you need to add `px`

Answer (score 0):

Your panel is 460px wide, which should be plenty of room four 100px wide boxes to fit in.  But with 5px of padding, a 4px border, and 5px of margin (on each side) your boxes are in fact 118px wide.

By default elements use `content-box` `box-sizing`.  This creates the box model I just described, where the content width is equal to the `width` style and the element gets bigger as margin/border/padding is added on.

I like to use `border-box` `box-sizing`.  With this style the whole element will only be the width of the `width` style and the content area gets smaller as margin/border/padding are applied.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```